# Group C* algebra realized as crossed product

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Can group $C^{\ast}$ algebras be realized as crossed product? For instance, do we need extra property on group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group. Then
$$C_u^*(\Gamma)\cong \mathbb{C}\rtimes \Gamma, \quad C_r^*(\Gamma) \cong \mathbb{C}\rtimes_r \Gamma$$
where $\Gamma$ acts on $\mathbb{C}$ trivially (in fact, there is only one action of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{C}$).